# Permission restrictions in Wagtail for "Reports" admin menu and its submenu items

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

**Goal:**
In my Wagtail website, I want to deny permission for all regular users (i.e. not superuser, not a moderator/editor) from accessing the "Reports" admin menu as well as all its submenu items such as "Locked Pages," "Workflows," "Site History," "Aging Pages" etc.

I don't want to create any custom submenu item such as "Pages with Unpublished Changes" under "Reports" admin menu.

I know how to hide the "Reports" admin menu completely from regular users. My goal is to deny permission, in addition to hiding.

**What I tried so far:**
Following https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6014 I created these 2 files:

1. views.py containing:

> ```
> from wagtail.admin.auth import permission_denied
> from wagtail.admin.views.reports import ReportView
> class MyReport(ReportView):
>     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
>             return permission_denied(request)
>         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

2. wagtail_hooks.py containing

> from .views import MyReport

**Desired behavior:**
Regular users should get "permission denied" error if they access any Reports submenu such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reports/site-history/